# Remove label from r plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This code :

```
x = c(0,0,1,3)
y = c(0,1,1,0)
df = data.frame(x , y)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_point(shape=1)+ #hollow circles
     geom_point(aes(size = 10))+
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(7, 7))
```

generates :

[image]

Why is the solid black sphere with 10,10 (circled in blue) generated ?

How can it be removed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need

```
 geom_point(size = 10)
```

rather than

```
 geom_point(aes(size = 10))
```

The former specifies the `size` property of your points directly.  The latter specifies a *mapping* between a variable which you have defined equal to 10 and the `size` property.